# ESTA no longer a student

Tags: esta

Last year I visited the USA the first time as a student. 
Hence I filled in no previous employer and that I was a student.

Since then I graduated and got a job. My ESTA is still valid for my
next trip, so I am wondering whether I can still use it? 
Or should I get a new one to reflect that I am no longer a student?

Comment: Circumstances change over the course of a visit or ESTA however a change from student to worker is not material to void the ESTA or make you ineligible for an ESTA. You're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not required to update your information, as the [ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization)](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel) is not a visa, but simply means you're eligible to travel to the US under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). Each approved ESTA application generally is valid for two years and allows for multiple visits to the United States within that period without having to apply for another ESTA approval.

Answer (score 2):

WHAT INFORMATION CAN I UPDATE?

Prior to submitting an electronic travel authorization application with the required payment information, you can update all application data fields except the passport number and passport issuing country. Once an application is approved, you can still update any one of the following fields:

- Email address
- Address in the U.S.

([Source](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e2s1#UPDATE) click What information can I update?)

You couldn't update if you wanted.

Beyond update, you need a new ESTA if you change your name, gender or country of citizenship or one of the eligibility questions change ([source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/kw/esta%20change%20name)) and these questions are:

1. Do you have a physical or mental disorder; or are you a drug abuser or addict; or do you currently have any of the following diseases (communicable diseases are specified pursuant to section 361(b) of the Public Health Service Act):

   - Cholera
   - Diphtheria
   - Tuberculosis, infectious
   - Plague
   - Smallpox
   - Yellow Fever
   - Viral Hemorrhagic Fevers, including Ebola, Lassa, Marburg, Crimean-Congo
   - Severe acute respiratory illnesses capable of transmission to other persons and likely to cause mortality.
2. Have you ever been arrested or convicted for a crime that resulted in serious damage to property, or serious harm to another person or government authority?
3. Have you ever violated any law related to possessing, using, or distributing illegal drugs?
4. Do you seek to engage in or have you ever engaged in terrorist activities, espionage, sabotage, or genocide?
5. Have you ever committed fraud or misrepresented yourself or others to obtain, or assist others to obtain, a visa or entry into the United States?
6. Are you currently seeking employment in the United States or were you previously employed in the United States without prior permission from the U.S. government?
7. Have you ever been denied a U.S. visa you applied for with your current or previous passport, or have you ever been refused admission to the United States or withdrawn your application for admission at a U.S. port of entry?
8. Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?
9. Have you traveled to, or been present in Iraq, Syria, Iran, Sudan, Libya, Somalia or Yemen on or after March 1, 2011?

Comment: But that report is six years old (it is dated May 2011).  The eligibility questions have changed since then, at least because of the so-called [Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act of 2015](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/158/text).

Comment: @phoog updated.