# Applying for ESTA while changing jobs

Tags: usa, esta

I have booked holiday to the United States in two months' time, and wish to apply for an ESTA under the Visa Waiver Program.

I am currently changing jobs - I have given notice to Employer A, and will start working for Employer B in one month's time.

When the ESTA asks for my employment details, do I give them Employer A (who I work for now), or Employer B (who I will be working for when I travel)?

Comment: There is no guarantee you will be working at company B in a months time. The forms are not requiring you to be a psychic or fortune teller. Anything could happen in the next month. Your employment details should be the present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current one will do. Your ESTA is valid for two years and many people will change jobs within that timeframe and yet ESTA doesn't require you to keep the answer for that question up to do date -- actually, you can't update it, you can only change your email and your address in the USA. Further, changing jobs doesn't invalidate your ESTA, see my [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93292/4188) for more.